# Unity: как прибавить значение по окончании кадра?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я делаю игру(о боже), и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Мне нужно плавно разгонять корабль так, чтобы спустя каждую секунду скорость становилась больше ровно на 13.Чтобы каждый кадр происходило что-то типа:

```
speed  0
accel  13
speed  speed + accel / fps
```

Можно было бы просто ждать секунду и увеличивать сразу на 13, но во первых это будет в  методе Update(), а во вторых нужна плавность(логично же, не так ли?)Попрошу помочь.На форуме юнити мне так никто и не ответил.

Код не прикладываю, он не нужен
Сам не могу, не особо знаю Unity API.(и что я пытаюсь сделать без знания API?)
Важна скорость исполнения кода.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не могу нормально написать код,  редактор все ругается, а пишу я с телефона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть `Time.deltaTime` - это время с прошлого кадра.

И есть где-то текущая скорость, скажем `m_CurrentSpeed`.

Тогда ваш метод `Update` будет таким:

```
private const float SPEED = 13f;

private void Update(){
    m_CurrentSpeed += SPEED*Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Скорость будет меняться плавно каждый кадр.

Comment: Я так понимаю, в результате в конце каждой секунды скорость станет больше на SPEED?

Comment: @JetFly по прошествии секунды да, станет больше на `SPPED`.

Comment: Сейчас буду испытывать.Благодарю за помощь.